# Using a new command inside a font command produces errors

Tags: typewriter

I have defined a new command as a macro as follows:

```
\newcommand{\Sel}[3]{S_{#1}^{#2, #3}}
```

I want every invocation of this command to consist of teletypefont (`\texttt`) so I tried changing the macro to:

```
\newcommand{\Sel}[3]{\texttt{S_{#1}^{#2, #3}}}
```

This gives me the following errors in the lines where `\Sel` is used in my Tex file:

- `Missing $ inserted.`
- `Extra }, or forgotten $.`

Trying to do something such as follows in the Tex file gives similar errors as well:

```
$\texttt{\Sel{x}{y}{z}}$
```

I'm hoping this is me misunderstanding the usage of commands inside commands.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are trying to put a text command in math mode? Try the other way around (put some `\mathtt` in there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Let us change your

\verb+\newcommand{\Sel}[3]{\texttt{S_{#1}^{#2, #3}}}+

into

\newcommand{\Sel}[3]{\mathtt{S_{#1}^{#2, #3}}}

${\Sel{x}{y}{z}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can observe, `\texttt` is changed into `\mathtt`, which behaves properly in math mode.